# Powerpivot retrieve cardinal value from data range of table2 to add as column to table1

Tags: excel, powerquery

Using Excel 365 Powerquery.

I have two datasources `table1` and `table2` with the following entries:

```
table1:

ID | salary
===========
1  |    10
2  |  1000

table2:
ID | inclminval | exclmaxval | class | display
20 |         0  |        100 |    P1 | Poor man
30 |       100  |       9999 |    P9 | Wealthy
```

I would like to append to table1: For every entry table1.salary,

- compare it to the range table2.inclminval <= table1.salary < table2.exclmaxval of table2 and
- use the matching corresponding entry of table2.class as a new computed column in table1.

Comment: Can you show us also desired output? Do you have also some code what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On table2, add column ... custom column ... with column name **custom** and formula **=1**

One table1, add column ... custom column ... with column name **custom** and formula **=1**

home .. merge queries ...

choose and match the **custom** column in both tables using a Full Outer join

[image]

Use the arrows atop the new column to [x] expand the **inclminval**, **exclmaxcal**, **class** and **display** columns

[image]

Add column ... custom column with formula similar to

```
= if [salary]>=[inclminval] and [salary]<[exclmaxcal] then "keep" else "remove"
```

Use arrow atop the new column to filter for [x] keep

Remove extra columns

Sample code for table1

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each 1),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"},Table2,{"Custom"},"Table2",JoinKind.FullOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"inclminval", "exclmaxcal", "class", "display"}, {"inclminval", "exclmaxcal", "class", "display"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table2", "Custom.1", each if [salary]>=[inclminval] and [salary]<[exclmaxcal] then "keep" else "remove"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each ([Custom.1] = "keep")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Custom", "inclminval", "exclmaxcal", "display", "Custom.1"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: I think I understand what you are doing. You expand the table2 and add every possible value between min and max into and additional column which you inner join with salary of table1. Now salary can of course be fractional, so this solution wont work?

Comment: Why not just cross join? `AddCustom = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Table2)`